# Efficiently/concurrently insert into unordered_map<>

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I need to gather some statistics for my project with the following algorithm (in Python):

```
stats = defaultdict(list)
for s in L:
     current = []
     for q in L:
         stats[s, q] = copy(current)
         current = f(current, s, q)
```

Because list `L` is large and `f()` and copying `current` take some time and project main language is C++ I decided to choose C++ and use its multithreading capabilities to implement my algorithm.

I moved that part:

```
         stats[s, q] = copy(current)
         current = f(current, s, q)
```

to a separate `std::async`, and locked `std::mutex` while inserting to `stats` but that made things slower. I tried to use  `tbb::concurrent_ordered_map` but that made things worse.

I wrote benchmark that reproduces its behavior: https://gist.github.com/myaut/94ee59d9752f524d3da8

Results for 2 x Xeon E5-2420 with Debian 7 for 800 entries in L:

```
single-threaded                       8157ms
async                mutex            10145ms
async with chunks    mutex            9618ms
threads              mutex            9378ms
async                tbb              10173ms
async with chunks    tbb              9560ms
threads              tbb              9418ms
```

I do not understand why TBB is slowest (it seem `tbb::concurrent_ordered_map` allocates larger amounts of memory, but for what). Are there any other options that can help me?

**EDIT**: I've updated my benchmark with suggested approaches (and reduced N to 800). It seem that problem is somewhere else...

- *chunks* - thanks to @Dave - now each `async` handles bundle of 20 sequential element of list
- *threads* - kind of threadpool as @Cameron suggests - I create 20 threads and each of them takes each 20th element of initial list.

**EDIT2**: I found one of the issues -- app consumes large amount of memory, so Xen Hypervisor became a bottleneck -- rebooted in native mode, now multithreaded modes it is only bit slower than uni-threaded

**EDIT3**: It seems the issue with multithreading is huge amount of allocations when copying `list`:

```
mprotect()
_int_malloc+0xcba/0x13f0
__libc_malloc+0x70/0x260
operator new(unsigned long)+0x1d/0x90
__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)+0x40/0x42
std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long)+0x2f/0x38
std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_create_storage(unsigned long)+0x23/0x58
std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_Vector_base(unsigned long, std::allocator<int> const&)+0x3b/0x5e
std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)+0x55/0xf0
void threaded_process<concurrent_map_of_list_of_lists>(concurrent_map_of_list_of_lists&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)::{lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int)#1}::operator()(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int) const+0x5f/0x1dc
_ZNSt12_Bind_simpleIFZ16threaded_processI31concurrent_map_of_list_of_listsEvRT_RKSt6vectorIiSaIiEEEUlN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKiS6_EESD_iE_SD_SD_iEE9_M_invokeIJLm0ELm1ELm2EEEEvSt12_Index_tupleIJXspT_EEE+0x7c/0x87
std::_Bind_simple<void threaded_process<concurrent_map_of_list_of_lists>(concurrent_map_of_list_of_lists&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)::{lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int)#1} (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int)>::operator()()+0x1b/0x28
std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void threaded_process<concurrent_map_of_list_of_lists>(concurrent_map_of_list_of_lists&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)::{lambda(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int)#1} (__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int const*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >, int)> >::_M_run()+0x1c/0x1e
std::error_code::default_error_condition() const+0x40/0xc0
start_thread+0xd0/0x300
clone+0x6d/0x90
```

The thing is when heap space exhausted, libc calls `grow_heap()`, which usually adds only one page, but then it calls `mprotect()` which calls `validate_mm()` in kernel. `validate_mm()` seem to lock entire VMA using semaphore. I replaced default `list` allocator with `tbb::scalable_allocator`, it rocks! Now `tbb` is 2 times faster than uni-processor approach.

Thanks for your help, I will use @Dave approach with chunks of job in `std::async`.

Comment: You're starting 1000 threads and letting them all duke it out for the same shared data structure. I'm surprised it's only twice as slow! Use a thread pool instead. EDIT: Actually, how many threads are started depends on your standard library implementation (it seems some *do* use thread pools). What platform are you on?

Comment: Since you are already using TBB you may as well use [`parallel_for`](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_for_func.htm) as this uses a thread pool.

Comment: @Cameron Debian 7, gcc 4.7 with libstdc++ 3. Thank you, I'll try to use threadpool

Comment: Can you try inserting into a local unordered_maps in your async task, then when the task is done, locking and merging the local map into the final map. You'll want the tasks to be big... ideally split all the work into as many tasks as you have cores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `f(current, s, q)` and copying `current` are trivially cheap it's going to be hard to make going wide with multithreading worth the overhead. However, I think I would use a lock free hash/unordered map (`tbb::concurrent_hash_map`? I don't know tbb) and launch the entire inner for loop with `std::async`. The idea is to launch a decent sized chunk of work with `std::async`, if it's too tiny and you launch a million trivial tasks the overhead of using `std::async` will eclipse the work the task has to do!

Also to note, when you use `std::async` you need to save off the returned `future` somewhere or it ends up blocking until the task is done in the `future`'s destructor, buying you multithreading overhead and no parallel processing at all. You may be running into that now. It's very obnoxious and I wish it didn't work that way.

Comment: > copying `current` are trivially cheap < No, it isn't :( It causing large number of `malloc()` s leading to `mprotect()` calls leading to concurrency.